# How to use -v volumes parameter in docker on Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: docker, volume, windows-subsystem-for-linux

My windows 10 version is 1803

I install docker fellow the link:

https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/setting-up-docker-for-windows-and-wsl-to-work-flawlessly

I try to use -v of docker like:

```
docker run -it -v ~/.aws:root/.aws/ ubuntu
```

I also try to use:

```
docker run -it -v $(realpath ~/.aws):/root/.aws ubuntu
```

But I find the volumes I want to mapping to docker system is not there.

when I do:

ls /root/.aws

there is always empty, how to mapping the data volumes on Windows Subsystem for linux?

Comment: Not sure of that, not a windows user, but docker run volume mapping format is `-v <host-path>:<container-path>`, thus I guess it might be smth. like, with windows inverted backslash flavor:
`docker run -it -v 'c:/foo/bar/aws':/root/.aws ubuntu`

Comment: the ~/.aws is not mapping in c:/foo/bar/.aws

Comment: vice versa, as I understand; you're trying to map some directory on Windows to Docker container, aren't you?
Anyway, despite windows is not native Docker habitat, I believe you're missing something trivial here

Comment: actually, I use subsystem Linux on widnows, I try to mapping the subsystem Linux directory to docker Container

Comment: The simple answer is WSL does not nicely work together with docker for windows. (At least I have not found a way). You can however mount native windows directories as docker volumes when you work in the windows shell..

Answer (score 6):

Docker for Windows runs atop Windows itself but has no knowledge of WSL.

In WSL:

- Distros can see the contents of Windows "drives" via the automatically mounted drives under `/mnt/<drive-letter>`
- Windows currently cannot reach into the filesystems of installed Linux distros. We're working to remedy this in future releases ;)

While Docker Engine itself cannot run within WSL, you can install [Docker for Windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/), and operate it from within WSL using the `docker` command-line tool, specifying the hostname via the `-h` argument, or export to `DOCKER_HOST` in your `.bashrc`.

You may find some of these tutorials useful:

- "[Setting Up Docker for Windows and WSL to Work Flawlessly](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/setting-up-docker-for-windows-and-wsl-to-work-flawlessly#configure-docker-for-windows)" by [@nickjanetakis](https://twitter.com/nickjanetakis)
- "[Running Docker containers on Bash on Windows](https://blog.jayway.com/2017/04/19/running-docker-on-bash-on-windows/)" by [@jayway](https://twitter.com/jayway)
- "[Docker in WSL](https://blog.wizardsoftheweb.pro/docker-in-wsl/)" by [@wizardsoftheweb](https://twitter.com/wizardsoftheweb)

Comment: Where can I learn more about the effort of mounting directories that are in a WSL machine?

Answer (score 3):

Answer above by Serge works, but I have done away with the cmd.exe part and just enclosed the Windows style path with single quotes.

I have the same issue with Docker for Desktop running inside WSL not reading my ~/.aws folder. My .aws folder is a soft link from C:\Users\.aws folder.

This is what worked for me:

```
docker run -v 'C:\Users\username\.aws':/root/.aws linux_image
```

Comment: This works for me! This should be answer to this question

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit old but I had the same issue.
Below is my configuration:

- Host OS: windows 10.0.17134 N/A Build 17134
- WSL:

  - 4.4.0-17134-Microsoft #706-Microsoft
  - Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
- Docker:

  - Docker-ce on WSL: Docker version 18.09.6, build 481bc77
  - Docker for Windows ce: Version 2.0.0.3 (31259) build 8858db3

The following solution is mostly useful when working on your own laptop with docker as a development environment. Shouldn't be used in production/test servers:

1. Share a folder between WSL and and Windows 10.
2. Copy the files needed to be shared with docker containers to the shared folder. 
   This allows the files to be visible/accessible to both WSL and Windows 10.
3. start a docker container binding a volume using the windows style volume name

Below are the commands:

1. On Windows Host machine, create a folder on the windows machine

   ```
   md %USERPROFILE%\dockerVolume
   ```
2. On WSL link that folder with the on the WSL user home folder

   ```
   ln -s `wslpath $(cmd.exe /C "echo %USERPROFILE%")|sed -e 's/\r//g'`/dockerVolume $HOME/dockerVolume
   ```
3. On WSL copy all the files you need to access from the Docker container in $HOME/dockerVolume
4. Then run you docker container as:

   ```
   docker run -it -v `cmd.exe /C "echo %USERPROFILE%"|sed 's/\r/\\\dockerVolume/g'`:/dockerVolume -w /dockerVolume --entrypoint /bin/bash <DOCKER IMAGE NAME>
   ```